# Unable to run Django project under Apache

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a Django project nice and running at 127.0.0.1:8000. I normally run it via:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

Now, what I want is to run it under `Apache`.

This is what I tried:

1. Installed and enabled mod_wsgi. It is working indeed, because when I     installed it I saw in the console: `"apache2_invoke: Enable module wsgi"`
2. Edited `000-default.conf` file in this way:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jacobian/django/apps/apps/wsgi.py
   <Directory /home/jacobian/django/apps/apps/>
       <Files wsgi.py>
          Require all granted
       </Files>
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   ```

That's it. I'm not sure what I'missing, but after I restart `apache` and go to `localhost`, in my browser I see a page from `/var/www` folder. Whereas I expect to see a django application. I guess I need to edit `apache2.conf` (how?) and do some other magic tricks (like download and install some extra magic stuff, make some magic apache configuration etc).

I tried dozens of tutorial, but none of them helped - either apache is not restarted or django project is not rendered in browser. So, I need some basic steps to follow to make it work.

**EDIT**

When I try to start apache without the tag `Files` inside the tag `Directory`, then apache fails to do that, but at the same time I see no additional messages in `error.log`. If, however, I use this tag like:

```
<Directory /home/jacobian/django/apps/apps/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

then I get a bunch of error messages in the `error.log`. This is the whole list:

```
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:45.901935 2015] [wsgi:warn] [pid 39222:tid 140543251101568] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:45.901995 2015] [wsgi:warn] [pid 39222:tid 140543251101568] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:45.902149 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 39222:tid 140543251101568] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:45.902186 2015] [core:notice] [pid 39222:tid 140543251101568] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.851442 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601] mod_wsgi (pid=41314): Target WSGI script '/home/jacobian/django/apps/apps/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.851498 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601] mod_wsgi (pid=41314): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/jacobian/django/apps/apps/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.851526 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.851557 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]   File "/home/jacobian/django/apps/apps/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.851696 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.851734 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.851800 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]     django.setup()
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.851818 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.851874 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.851892 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.851994 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]     self._setup(name)
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.852013 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.852038 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.852053 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__    
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.852072 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601]     % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
[Mon Sep 21 13:55:46.852097 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 41314:tid 140543032010496] [client 127.0.0.1:50601] ImportError: Could not import settings 'apps.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named apps.settings
```

I'm not sure what can be wrong with `wsgi.py` file. It's a standard file created with `$ django-admin startproject apps`. Probably we miss `WSGIPythonPath` variable in the apache `conf` file. But I'm not sure where it should point to in the real world case and not in some abstract case. If I follow some tutorials and set it like `WSGIPythonPath /home/jacobian/django/apps/`, then apache is unable to start. So, I do not know what can I do.

Comment: It depends what is in the rest of the default config and if there are any more enabled sites that overwite your virtualhost

Comment: In `000-default.conf` I have no other sites made available.

Comment: @ Bas van Stein. I updated my question, so that it shows how the whole `000-default.conf` looks like.

Comment: You forgot to set the `document root` in the conf file.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-a-virtualenv)? you seem to have neither of the options setup correctly

Comment: @ Bas van Stein Where it should point to? `/home/jacobian/django/apps/apps/` or `/home/jacobian/django/apps/` ?

Comment: @ Hedde van der Heide. Documentation you are pointing to, starts from "If you install your project’s Python dependencies inside a virtualenv, you’ll need". But I'm not using virtualenv.

Comment: BTW. If I add `WSGIPythonPath /home/jacobian/django/apps/` to my `000-default.conf`, then apache is unable to start. So, I think documentation does not cover all situations. It says "The official mod_wsgi documentation is fantastic;" But I wish it better had "fantastic examples" that covered all situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually its very easy to configure apache2 + wsgi for django; but if you miss out any step it can be cumbersome to trace out the issue; just try to iterate over the steps mentioned below, it will help you trace out the issue.

Please find the [django documenatation on this here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

Here are the steps you might want to try:

[Edit to fit user needs]

*RENAMED certain fields to make it more easier to understand

Lets say you created you django project in /home/jacobian/django/

```
django_project/
|-- django_project
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- wsgi.py
`-- manage.py
```

It should be similar to above tree your path to wsgi specified in apache
will be:

`/home/jacobian/django/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py`

or in other terms

PROJECT_PATH would mean `/home/jacobian/django/`
PROJECT_NAME would mean `django_project`
[Specific to Ubuntu]

1. Install Apache

   apt-get install apache2
2. Install mod_wsgi

   apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
3. Make a WSGI handler script; usaully go like this depending on the version of django installation:

   ```
   import os
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_project.settings")

   from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
   application = get_wsgi_application()
   ```
4. Put it all in apache conf by writing it to a new file say `sitename.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     WSGIScriptAlias / PROJECT_PATH/PROJECT_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/wsgi.py
     Alias /static PROJECT_PATH/PROJECT_NAME/static/
     Alias /media PROJECT_PATH/PROJECT_NAME/media/

    ServerName www.example.com

    <Directory />
      Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
    <Directory PROJECT_PATH/PROJECT_NAME/>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. Enable that site

   sudo a2ensite sitename.conf
6. Restart Apache

   sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: And in terms of a real Django project that I have (located in `/home/jacobian/django/apps/`), how `WEBSITE_PATH` should look like in your example? I'm asking this, because I find it a little confusing when in tutorials they use both `.../website/website/` and `../website/` (or `../apps/apps/` and `/apps/` in my case). So, I'm not sure what folder is what. And by the way, why you are refering to `/var/www/WEBSITE_FOLDER`. So even if my project is located in `/home/jacobian/django/apps/`, should I prepend this path with `/var/www/`??

Comment: Can you, please, change paths in `sitename.conf` to real ones, that correspond not to some abstract site or project, but to some real Django project located in some real folder, say, `/home/jacobian/django/apps/`? Thanks!

Comment: in place of `sitename.conf` you can place any name just for reference I have already given a absolute path for placing the `sitename.conf` in Ubuntu systems. @Jacobian take a look at the edit if it makes more sense to you.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm asking not about the `sitename.conf`, but about its contents, precisely, about `WEBSITE_PATH` and `/var/www/WEBSITE_FOLDER`. I'm not sure how they should look like in real world, when there is a real world Django project located at `/home/jacobian/django/apps/`

Comment: @Jacobian no problem, if you can give me the tree or structure of your project I will write a conf file for you specific to your system. If you are using ubuntu just go in you project folder and say `tree my_django_project` and also give me full path of where the `my_django_project` is located.

Comment: Thank you, akm! I have a similar folder structure, like it is now in your answer.

Comment: I've just checked it and it does not work. With such a `conf` file when I try to restart apache, I get this error message "Job for apache2.service failed". So, at this moment your solution does not work. BTW, In many other tutorials I saw a tag `Files` which is not present in your conf file.

Comment: BTW. I edited `settings.py` file - added `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']`. So there is still a lot of issues which remain unsolved and there is a need for a step-by-step Working solution. What I've seen by now are step-by-step non-working solutions or simply something which has become outdated years ago.

Comment: Could you pull the apache logs from `/var/log/apache2/error.log` there must be some kind of typo ? also tell which version of `django` you are using. `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` will be needed only if your turn the `debug` to 'False'.

Comment: Please, have a look at my updated question. It now contains log info.

Comment: Hm. Apache does not like `Order allow, deny`, but prefers `Order allow,deny`. So, now at least apache starts with configuration from your example, that is without the `Files` tag. But still I get the very same list of error messages in `error.log`: `Target WSGI script '/home/jacobian/django/apps/apps/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module` etc.

Comment: I finally found the working combination =)) In your answer you just have to change `point 3`, that is to add these two lines `PROJECT_ROOT = 'PROJECT_PATH'` and `sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT)`

Comment: @Jacobian you are correct, This happens with older version of django. Thats why I pointed it depends on the version of django you might be using; just incase code mentioned in the answer will work perfectly for django 1.8.